# How to do vector operations on elements in a list in a data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `data`. Data has a column called `predicted_OL` which is comprised of lists. I want to create a new column that is an operation on an element in a list in `predicted_OL`. For example, I want to do:

```
data$new_column1 <- data$predicted_OL$fit + 1
data$new_column2 <- data$predicted_OL$r2 * 2
```

How do I do this? See example below of what is inside of `data$predicted_OL`:

```
> data$predicted_OL[1]

[[1]]
[[1]]$fit
           1 
-0.005725406 

[[1]]$se.fit
[1] 0.0004004448

[[1]]$df
[1] 249

[[1]]$residual.scale
[1] 0.004585551

[[1]]$r2
[1] 0.04053683
```

EDIT: Hmm, I have been trying to create a reproducible sample, but for some reason that isn't working. My attempt below produces an error that I can't seem to fix.

```
modeldata <- data.frame(X = sample(1:20), Y = sample(1:20))
reg <- lm(Y ~ X, data = modeldata)

sample_pred <- function(model,value)
{
    next_obs <- data.frame(X = c(value))

    result <- predict(model,next_obs,se.fit=TRUE)
    c(result, value = value)
}

sampledata <- data.frame(X=sample(1:5))
sampledata$predictedY <- sapply(sampledata$X, sample_pred, model = reg)
```

Comment: Please `dput` a small sample of your data frame (see [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)) and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: See edit above - tried to create a sample, but can't seem to get that to work. Frustrating :/

Comment: The structure of the `sampledata` does not fit the one of `data`. Please use `dput(data)` to provide reproducible data. If it's too large, you can post it at pastebin.com and provide the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `sapply` in combination with `[[`:

```
data$new_column1 <- sapply(data$predicted_OL, "[[", "fit") + 1

data$new_column2 <- sapply(data$predicted_OL, "[[", "r2") * 2
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I deal with NAs in data$predicted_OL? Running your code gives me Error in FUN(X[[445L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @user2374133 It appears your data has a messy structure. It is not reproducible with the information you have provided.